# Can't delete images from a Docker proxy / mirror / cache registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-proxy

Running the `registry:2` image via docker-compose `1.27.4`, docker itself is at `19.03.13`.

The registry is configured as a ["pull through cache"](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#proxy), also referred to as "proxy" or "mirror" by some. The setup is very basic and follows the official documentation:

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
  delete:
    enabled: true
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
```

When using the standard procedures to delete an image on this registry via the API...

1. find tag name

   ```
   export HEADER="Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
   curl -s -H $HEADER https://<HOST>/v2/<CATALOG>/tags/list
   ```
2. find corresponding SHA

   ```
   curl -sI -k -H $HEADER https://<HOST>/v2/<CATALOG>/manifests/<TAG>
   ```
3. delete via SHA

   ```
   curl -H $HEADER -X DELETE https://<HOST>/v2/<CATALOG>/manifests/<SHA>
   ```

...I get a 404 for the last command:

```
404 page not found
```

When I do the same with the `proxy` bit commented out in the registry configuration, it works.

This feels eerily familiar to [not being able to push against such a "pull through cache" registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610215/unable-to-push-image-to-a-docker-registry-configured-as-proxy-cache), which, to be fair, is documented. This use case isn't - or is it?

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is for running a delete against the cache? Are you trying to save space on the cache, flush a stale entry, or want to delete the image from the upstream registry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pull through cache functionality of the `registry:2` image is designed for exactly that, pulling. Any other actions, like push or delete, aren't supported and are expected to give errors. To delete the manifest at the source, you'll want to run the delete command against that registry. I don't believe there's any API to prematurely remove a manifest from only the cache, it's a fixed 7 day expiration time.

Comment: Thanks for answering, to answer your question above: My concrete use case is being able to remove certain images that went in there by accident. If I understand correctly, I'm not supposed to do that, but let the registry fix itself by weeding out stale images? In my example that would mean ensuring nobody pulls these unwanted images for 7 days?

Comment: @zb226 I believe it's 7 days regardless of whether it's been pulled. Only option I know of to clean out the cache manually is to restart with the storage/volume reset. It will automatically repopulate as images get pulled through.

Comment: From freshly acquired own experience: you're right with the unconditional 7 days. It's a bit sad that these informations aren't officially documented (besides the sources). Well, now at least we have this SO answer for people to google for. Thanks again.

Comment: you need to run the gc for the 7 day limit to free space right ?

Answer (score 0):

like any normal registry you can delete files directly on the disk
data/docker/registry/v2/repositories/...
in this folder there are only manifests, so you then need to run garbage collector.
i suppose the 7 days @BMitch is talking about also needs the GC to run because when i ran it it freed >40go and i am now happy with 400mo and everything still working.